# How to use Javascript datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, yui

I want to use Javascript to implement a datatable which can be reordered by clicking table head.

As I known jQuery and YUI have this plugin. But there's a further requirement that is user don't need to click table head but click another place out of table and the data table should be reordered normally.

Is there any suggestion?

Comment: You can take a look at Google visualization API http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls.html    http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/examples.html There's also Dojo grid http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/grid/index?action=show&redirect=dojox/grid.  As for clicking outside, you can easily create your own event onclick that'll re-arrange table to the default state.

Answer (score 0):

Check out jqGrid

http://www.trirand.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the simulate utility to get the stated behavior

```
Y.one("#node").simulate("click");
```

[Here](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/event/#eventsimulation) is more info on simulating event.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery datatables you can do something like this in your click event:

```
var columnIndexToSort = 0,
    sortAcending = true;

$("#table").fnSort([[columnIndexToSort, sortAcending ? 'asc' : 'desc']]);
```

This will cause jquery datatables to sort and redraw the table for you. The jquery datatables plugin is very powerful and I find it harder to find something it can't do rather than something it can.